# How does the following `src='${loadingGif}'` work inside angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I'm reading the book `ng-book` on angular 2 and there is the following:

```
let loadingGif: string = ((<any>window).__karma__) ? '' : require('images/loading.gif');

@Component({
  selector: 'youtube-search',
  template: `
  <div class='container'>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>YouTube Search
          <img
            style="float: right;"
            *ngIf="loading"
            src='${loadingGif}' />
        </h1>
      </div>
```

I'm interested in this part:

```
src='${loadingGif}'
```

The short note in the book says the following:

> Notice that our img has a src of ${loadingGif} - that loadingGif
>   variable came from a require statement earlier in the program. Here
>   we’re taking advantage of webpack’s image loading feature. If you want
>   to learn more about how this works, take a look at the webpack config
>   in the sample code for this chapter or checkout
>   image-webpack-loader⁴².

But there are no details. Can somebody please how does it all work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only works with inline templates (template in `*.ts` file) but not when the template is in an `*.html` file (like `templateUrl: './my.component.html`).

```
src='${loadingGif}'
```

Is TypeScript string interpolation and not related to Angular. It replaces `${loadingGif}` with the content of `loadingGif`

Comment: What do you mean with "protected"?

Comment: No prob. Not too easy to reason about. Its not data binding though. `${loadingGif}` is replaced in the template before the template is compiled by Angular. If `loadingGif` would change at runtime, the `src` attribute wouldn't change. For this to happen you would need to use Angular binding like `src="{{loadingGif}}"` or `[src]="loadingGif"`, but in this case `loadingGif` would need to be a field or getter in your components class.